# Xor doesn't fire

Tags: vb.net, xor

No more answers please, the problem was solved. Skip to the end of the question to see what i have done wrong.

---

I am running the following `Function`to read the syntax of a specific standard either by `FilePath` (`Function` reads the `file first` to get the string) or by the `Text` itself (`skips file reading`)

```
Public Function ReadStandard(Optional ByVal FilePath As String = Nothing, _
Optional ByVal Standard_Text As String = Nothing) As Boolean
```

to make this possible only one of those parameter must be set, while the other must not be set. I do not want to use a function like

```
Public Function ReadStandard(str as String, isFilePath as Booelean) As Boolean
```

So to make this possible I want to use Xor, since it should do the exact job 
(if you pass 2 Booleans to XOR it should only return True, when A != B). Doing some research i found that this works in vb.net: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/csw1x2a6.aspx)

But for some reason it doesn't work for me;

```
If IsNothing(FilePath) Xor IsNothing(Standard_Text) Then (...)
```

Is there a reason for it? Or did I forget what i learned back in the days?

---

Turns out that I just mixed something up in my logic. In the following function I forgot to put the `Not` into the `If-Statement`

```
If Not (IsNothing(FilePath) Xor IsNothing(Standard_Text)) Then
  Throw New ArgumentException("FilePath or Standard_Text must be set.")
  Return False
End If
```

Comment: Two separate functions `ReadStandardFromFile()` and `ReadStandardFromText()` are probably more reasonable. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: There are tons of different ways to the the job for this case. But that's not the point. For future projects it will sure be helpful to be able to use Xor.  That's why I'm asking. To understand the VB.Net logic of Xor.

Comment: I think you understand it. That's why I asked what you mean by "does not work". How do you verify it and what inputs do you provide?

Comment: Inputs are `ReadStandard()` (Which is twice nothing) and `("asd","asd")` (Which is twice something). Both do not return true. .. WAAAIIIT ..... Give me a minute to sort my thoughts... you probably see that there is something spinned in my head right now

Comment: Both examples should not return true. As you said, A != B must be fulfilled, which it is not in these cases. Btw, you might also want to consider the `Is Nothing` operator, i.e. `If FilePath Is Nothing Xor ...`.

Comment: Thats the "Waaaiiiit" point... as i was typing i realized that myself. Thanks anyways! Going to put the code this was used to into the Question.

Comment: BTW, to check if a string is `Nothing` or empty (`""`) you can use `If FilePath = "" `

Comment: @slai I'd rather use String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath.Trim) for this one. But since I am using If io.File.exists(FilePath) that's not a problem. Syntax reading takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR can be thought of as binary addition without carry.

```
    If False Xor False Then '0+0
        Stop
    End If

    If True Xor False Then '1+0
        Stop
    End If

    If False Xor True Then '0+1
        Stop
    End If

    If True Xor True Then '1+1
        Stop
    End If
```

Comment: Problem was solved alread and undestanding Xor was never a question. But your explanation is perfectly on point and well good to understand for those, who dont know Xor yet. I'm going to mark it as the answer so people stop posting here. Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

how does your call look like? I tried your sample and it is working.

```
Public Function ReadStandard(Optional FilePath As String = Nothing,   Optional Standard_Text As String = Nothing) As Boolean

    ReadStandard = False
    If IsNothing(FilePath) Xor IsNothing(Standard_Text) Then
        ReadStandard = True
    End If

End Function
```

Calling like this (X is example path) delivers the right answer:

```
ReadStandard(,)         --> False
ReadStandard(, "X")     --> True
ReadStandard("X",)      --> True
ReadStandard("X", "X")  --> False
```

Be aware of calling like `ReadStandard("", "X")`, because that means `FilePath` is not empty.

BR

Comment: You're to late mate. Read the comments of the question please :-)

Comment: Argh :) But if this is your solution, you could simply use  ´If IsNothing(FilePath) = IsNothing(Standard_Text) Then´

Comment: Sure, that'd be a simple solution. But i think Xor makes it more readable in this case, becaue Xor's meaning exactly says one MUST be set, while the other must not be set. However, its solved and thank you for your advice as well.